# how to reload ruby inserted into javascript - turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a rails 4 app with turbolinks. I insert ruby variables into my javascript however when I click a link, the variables don't get reset since the javascript isn't being reset. How do I make sure the each time a user goes to another page, it reloads the ruby inserted into the javascript?

EDIT MORE INFO:

```
pubnub.subscribe({
      channel : "#{@customer.channel}",
      message : function(message){
        if(message.customer_id == #{@customer.id}){
          debugger;
          $('#message').append($('<li>').text("#{@customer.first_name}" + ': (' + "#{Time.now.utc.to_s(:time)}" + ') '+ message.text));
        }
      }
    });
```

basically, if I'm looking at @customer.id's page, it works...then when I click to antoher page, @customer.id is the same as the previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to never put Ruby variables into your JavaScript.

I prefer to use data attributes in the DOM to pass values from the server to the client code:

```
<div class='my-pubnub-widget' data-pubnub-opts= '<%= @ruby_hash.to_json %>'></div>
```

And in JavaScript

```
function setupPubnub(opts) {
  pubnub.subscribe({
    channel : opts.channel,
    message : function(message){
      if(message.customer_id == opts.id){
        $('#message').append($('<li>').text(opts.first_name + ': (' + opts.time + ') '+ message.text));
      }
    }
  });
}

$(document).on('page:load', function () { // turbolinks ready event
  $('.my-pubnub-widget').each(function () {
    setupPubnum($(this).data('pubnub-opts'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this, pass the needed info as data to html elements and move the javascript to an asset file.

**html**

```
<div id='customer-info' data-channel='<%= @customer.channel %>' data-customer-id='<% @customer.id %>'</div>
```

**JS (coffee)**

```
if $('#customer-info').length
  pubnub.subscribe
    channel: $('#customer-info').data('channel')
    message: (message) ->
    if message.customer_id == $('#customer-info').data('customer-id')
      alert('same user')
```

And since you're using turbolinks, make sure that the code runs when the page is loaded via turbolinks.  The easiest way to make sure of this is to use the [jquery-turbolinks gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

Comment: you just solved an issue i've been trying to hack-fix for days...thank you sir!!